# Merge two tables without common column in sql

Tags: sql, merge

I have two tables A and B. Table A contains field 'number'. Table B contains 'number_start' and 'number_end'. 
I want to merge these two tables such that final table contains details from both the table where number is between number_start and number_end.

I want to achieve this in redshift /sql. let me know if anyone has some clue.

Comment: How do the two tables relate to each other?

Comment: Basically source of these two table is different and i want to map them into one table. In table A its details is given number wise while in other table it is given range wise.

Comment: do you mean `between` as number_start < number < number_end or do you mean it is the second column?

Comment: @rupali ok, but how do they relate to each other, what logic dictates which number should like to the numberstart and number end

Comment: @Dennis : i mean between as number_start < number < number_end

Comment: @Matt : Number is decimal version of ip_address. Number_start is decimal version of ip_start and Number_end is decimal version ip_end.

Comment: @rupali Yes but what logic is there to say which number/ip/whatever links to each other, i assume you dont want them randomly assigning to each other

Answer (score 2):

Perform this Join Operation

```
Select a.Number,b.EndNumber,b.StartNumber
from A a join B b
on  a.Number >= b.StartNumber and a.Number <= b.EndNumber
```

Comment: thanks this query make sense! I will update it little bit as per my need. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use join statement. Try This.

```
select t1.numbers from t1,t2 where t1.numbers>t2.min and t1.numbers<t2.max;
```

Comment: the number of table1 must be between the two numbers of table2, a normal join will not solve this.

Comment: ya ok Now only I understand use case I try it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.`number`,t2.`end_number`, t2.`start_number` FROM table1 t1, `table2` t2
WHERE `number` >= start_number
AND number <=end_number
```

do you want some thing like this?
[Please check this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5f28/1)

Comment: 1) SQLfiddle is very usefull, but you should post your code in SO, not just link. 2) Why are you using nested SELECT?

Comment: @LS_dev thank u for your suggestions and i forgot to remove the upper select it will work fine in one select

Answer (score 0):

If both table is not related with each other then you can use this query

```
select CONVERT(varchar, A.number_start) + CONVERT(varchar,B.number) + Convert(varchar,A.number_end)     from A cross join B
```

Or If this table has foreign key,then you can use inner join in this query

Comment: this will not work because of this comment from the author: `@Dennis : i mean between as number_start < number < number_end`