# Merge two tables without common columns in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is is inspired/based by/on the previous one, [Merge two tables without common column in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267902/merge-two-tables-without-common-column-in-sql).

What if condition is worse, i.e. we do not have the column `endNumber` in table B for that post. For my case here, I have table `A` and I don't have the endTime of each orgStatus for table `A`. We know the startedTime of the second orgStatus is in fact the endedtime of first orgStatus.

```
+-------+-----------+----------------------+
| orgId | orgStatus | startedTime          |
+-------+-----------+----------------------+
|   1   |    1      | 2011-12-14 09:25:21  |
|   1   |    2      | 2011-12-14 10:26:21  |
|   1   |    3      | 2011-12-14 11:27:21  |
|   1   |    4      | 2011-12-14 12:25:21  |
|   2   |    1      | 2011-12-14 10:26:21  |
|   2   |    2      | 2011-12-14 10:50:21  |
|   2   |    3      | 2011-12-14 11:28:21  |
|   2   |    4      | 2011-12-14 15:25:21  |
+-------+-----------+----------------------+
```

The above is Table `A`, and table `B` is as follows.

```
+-------+-----------+----------------------+
| orgId | eventid   | createdTime          |
+-------+-----------+----------------------+
|   1   |    id1    | 2011-12-14 09:26:21  |
|   1   |    id2    | 2011-12-14 10:27:21  |
|   2   |    id3    | 2011-12-14 10:27:22  |
|   2   |    id4    | 2011-12-14 10:51:21  |
|   1   |    id5    | 2011-12-14 11:28:21  |
|   2   |    id6    | 2011-12-14 11:29:21  |
|   1   |    id7    | 2011-12-14 12:26:21  |
|   2   |    id8    | 2011-12-14 15:26:21  |
+-------+-----------+----------------------+
```

The desired result should be

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| orgId | orgStatus | eventCount|
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|   1   |     1     |     1     |
|   1   |     2     |     1     |
|   1   |     3     |     1     |
|   1   |     4     |     1     |
|   2   |     1     |     1     |
|   2   |     2     |     1     |
|   2   |     3     |     1     |
|   2   |     4     |     1     |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

To allocate the `event` to the correct `orgId`, `orgStatus`, I think of joining these two tables with same `orgId`, while the other condition is complex. The `createdTime` of an event should be between two `startedTime`s, of corresponding `orgStatus`. While for the last `orgStatus` of each `orgId`, we just check if the `event` is created after the `createdTime` of the `orgStatus`.

I think of creating a column `endedTime` for table `A`, but How can I put into entry the information which is not in the same row (the information we need is in the next row).

So the first step I think of is to modify table `A` as follows,

```
+-------+-----------+----------------------+----------------------+
| orgId | orgStatus | startedTime          | endedTime            |
+-------+-----------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1   |    1      | 2011-12-14 09:25:21  | 2011-12-14 10:26:21  |
|   1   |    2      | 2011-12-14 10:26:21  | 2011-12-14 11:27:21  |
|   1   |    3      | 2011-12-14 11:27:21  | 2011-12-14 12:25:21  |
|   1   |    4      | 2011-12-14 12:25:21  | inf                  |
|   2   |    1      | 2011-12-14 10:26:21  | 2011-12-14 10:50:21  |
|   2   |    2      | 2011-12-14 10:50:21  | 2011-12-14 11:28:21  |
|   2   |    3      | 2011-12-14 11:28:21  | 2011-12-14 15:25:21  |
|   2   |    4      | 2011-12-14 15:25:21  | inf                  |
+-------+-----------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

I get stuck here, how can I get information which is not at the same row.

Comment: @Barmar I updated my problem with my efforts too, try to show what I have done before asking.

Comment: You need to show your attempted query. It seems like you just need a join on `createdTime BETWEEN startedTime AND endedTime`

Comment: @Barmar Yes, the last table is my goal, I think. If I created the last table, I can just join modified `A` with `B` on `orgId` and `createdTime` BETWEEN `startedTime` and `endedTime`. But I have no idea of how to creat a new column `endedTime` like this.

Comment: Search SO for `[mysql] get next row` to find many questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar ok, I solved it. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Barmar 's comment.
I would solve this problem myself.

Fisrt, I modify table `A` with a new column `endedTime`. The query is as follows,

```
select a.orgId as orgId, 
       a.orgStatus as orgStatus,
       a.startedTime as startedTime, 
       ifnull(b.startedTime, '2030-01-01 00:00:00') as endedTime
from A as a 
left join A as b 
  on a.orgId = b.orgId and a.orgStatus = b.orgStatus - 1
order by orgId, orgStatus
```

The above query created the last table, then we can join this new table with table `B` on `orgId` and `createdTime` between `startedTime` and `endedTime`.

The complete solution is as follows,

```
select a.orgId as orgId, 
       a.orgStatus as orgStatus, 
       count(b.eventid) as eventCount
from (
      select a.orgId as orgId, 
             a.orgStatus as orgStatus, 
             a.startedTime as startedTime, 
             ifnull(b.startedTime, '2030-01-01 00:00:00') as endedTime
      from A as a 
      left join A as b 
        on a.orgId = b.orgId and a.orgStatus = b.orgStatus - 1
      order by orgId, orgStatus
     ) as a 
left join B as b
  on a.orgId = b.orgId and b.createdTime between a.startedTime and a.endedTime
group by orgId, orgStatus
order by orgId, orgStatus;
```

which gives the desired table.